# Getting last process ID in bash script with $! doesn't always work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pid

I am a little down the rabbit hole here..

I had a little script that should just start a dotnet process into the background and save the process id.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "killing $(cat ~/currentPID)"
kill `cat ~/currentPID`
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging && cd ~/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/ && dotnet Project.dll --urls=http://localhost:42666 &
echo "$!" > ~/currentPID
```

This works from time to time but most of my tries, the PID would be $! + 1

Even if I try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "killing $(cat ~/currentPID)"
kill `cat ~/currentPID`
echo "killing $(cat ~/currentPID2)"
kill `cat ~/currentPID2`
echo "killing $(cat ~/currentPID3)"
kill `cat ~/currentPID3`
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging && cd ~/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/ && dotnet Project.dll --urls=http://localhost:42666 &
CURRPID="$!"
sleep 3
echo "$(($CURRPID + 1))" > ~/currentPID2
echo "$(($CURRPID + 2))" > ~/currentPID3
echo "$CURRPID" > ~/currentPID
```

it will be currentPID3 + 1

I guess I will use pkill -P but anyone got any ideas what's going on here?! :)

PS: ps aux says that currentPID is the process of the shell script itself. Which makes sense. The other PIDs will be unassigned though.

Comment: This is because `$!` returns the PID of the _shell_ that you forked, the shell that executes the complex command line, not the PID of the single `dotnet` process. (That may well be PID + 1 or just about whatever else.) There is no reason for `&&` after `export` anyway; it just doesn’t fail. To stop on things that can fail, prefer `set -e` or the like. `export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging; pushd ~/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/; dotnet Project.dll --urls=http://localhost:42666 & echo "$!" > ~/currentPID; popd` … and then the `kill` should be getting the right PID … `kill $(< ~/currrentPID)`

Comment: Forgot to mention: If you do end up with a structured command and a PID of a (sub)shell instead of the PID of the desired process, `kill -- -$(< ~/currentPID)` can help. (Notice the `-`.) As long as the system / environment is reasonably standards-compliant, a negative PID sends a signal not just to the PID itself, but also to its entire process group / subtree. But in general it’s better to _not_ `fork()` a complex command and get the right PID from `$!` directly.